# How do I use kwargs as flags without needing =True?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I'm working on a python module that fetches, downloads/updates and then automatically installes other modules. How do I use **kwargs (or an alternative) without needing =True on the end for a "flags" system?

I'm not very experienced in general so I'm not sure what do do here

Currently, for the silent flag to work, It has to look like this:

```py
pyup.imp(["psutil","shutil","os","sys","pyinstaller"],silent=True)
```

but I want the call function to look like this:

```py
pyup.imp(["psutil","shutil","os","sys","pyinstaller"],silent)
```

The function itself looks like this (in pyup.py):

```py
def imp(libs = [], *args, **kwargs):
```

*where libs[] is the array containing the wanted libraries.*

**How do I make the function call not require "=True"?**

Comment: There are ways of making this work but beware that this wouldn’t be “pythonic” and is therefore generally discouraged.

Comment: As a side note, be very careful with a mutable default argument (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: To me, the notation `imp([...], silent)` implies that silent is some sort of local variable passed to the function. `silent=True` is more readable in my opinion.

Comment: The way to make that happen would be for either a) `silent` to be explicitly positional (`imp(libs, silent, *args, **kwargs)`) or b) for you to imply where `silent` is in `*args` like `silent, *args = args`. Also, you don't want `lists` or other mutable data structures to be defaults in functions

Comment: Python prefers being explicit, and `silent=True` is explicit. So I'd recommend using what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a series of string flags to your function (as if it were a terminal application), you coud pass them as unnamed positional arguments via `*args`.

```
def imp(libs=[], *args):
    silent = '--silent' in args

# somewhere else
imp([...], '--silent')
```

Comment: They would need to be strings though, i don't think your notation can be made to work in python.

Comment: This works well. Just wondering, would it be possible to "declare" --silent as a blank variable or something similar to acheive a call like: ```python
imp([...], --silent)```

Comment: No that's not possible. If you insert a name like that, python will always look for it in the scope where the function is called. Only the `silent=True` syntax interprets `silent` in the scope of the function (or passes it to `**kwargs` if no parameter `silent` is defined).

Answer (score 0):

If we defined a function like this, you cannot:

```
def imp(libs = [], *args, **kwargs):
```

But if you defined the function like this, you can:

```
def imp(libs = [], silent = True, *args, **kwargs):
```

and indeed, just as you posted, you can have this run without problem:

```
silent = True
imp(["psutils", ...], silent)
```

only that inside the function, `kwargs` will never have the key `silent` as it is being held by another parameter.

Comment: The problem is, this is a module, so I don't think that  ```silent = True``` would be called

Comment: I guess the answer will be "no" then.